# How to programmatically remove the "Detach" context menu item from an Eclipse RCP view toolbar?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am working on an Eclipse RCP application and have a view where I want to remove the "Detach" context menu item from the toolbar programmatically. The "Detach" item appears when right-clicking on the toolbar of the view, and I want to remove it to customize the toolbar behavior. How can I achieve this programmatically?

Comment: If this is an MPart in the Application.e4xmi you just add `NoDetach` to the Tags in the part description.

Comment: This is an e3 application , the custom view is created which extends from ViewPart

Comment: You probably need to find the MPart corresponding to the view, maybe using EPartService.findPart and add the NoDetach to the part tags.

Comment: What problem does denying the user this functionality solve?

Comment: In my RCP application, I don't have perspectives.if the user detach and close the view, their is no chance to open/ restore the view again. Only option is to restart the appln with new workspace.

Comment: @greg-449 I tried using this code IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench(); EPartService partService = workbench.getService(EPartService.class); MPart part = partService.findPart(ViewPart.ID); if (part != null) { // Add the NoDetach tag to the part's tags part.getTags().add("NoDetach"); } but no luck, its still showing "Detach" context menu

Comment: Sorry but I haven't written an e3 app for a long time, I don't know anymore about what might be required.